# sendkeys not working when using javascript executor in selenium test

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, ui-testing

I am trying to send-keys using javascript executor, my test script is shown below. I can see the right username and password entered into the form box, but somehow when I click login it doesn't log in. I am pretty sure that these are the correct sign-on parameters and work perfectly fine manually. I did use both ways to click submit button, javascript and slenium way

```
    JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
    je.executeScript("document.getElementById('userid').value='username'");
    je.executeScript("document.getElementById('password').value='password'");
    # je.executeScript("document.getElementById('Submit').click()");
    webDriver.findElement(By.id("Submit")).click();
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: please add the html , screenshot of elements etc

Comment: you can try out the sendkeys() which is available in selenium. is it not working?